# Populate form data based on previous field

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form that i want to auto populate the last 2 fields based on field 2 data.  Here is my form.

```
<form method="post">
<table>  <tr><b>Add new data using form below</b></tr>       
 <tr><td>  Keyword:  </td><td> <input type="text" name="keyword" id="keyword"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td> Block?: </td><td><input type="text" name="block" id="block"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td> Phone #:</td><td> <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone"><br></td></tr>
<tr><td> Reason: </td><td> <input type="text" name="reason" id="reason"><br></td></tr>
  <tr><td> </td><td align="left"> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit  Data"></td></tr>
    </table>
      </form>
```

So the phone and reason will auto populate based on the block number entered.  No necessarily looking for someone to do it.. maybe just guide me in a direction to get answer.

Comment: What have you tried so far to get it to work? What code do you have other than the form itself?

Comment: you can post those values or send them in sesseion

Comment: How will you know what to put in phone and reason based on the block number?

Comment: please tell how you will get the data ? 1) with ajax get data from some table 2) form javascript array 3) some fix values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like a job for jQuery. Try a blur function for #block field:

```
$('#block').blur(function() {
 // get value, based on this, populate value of your other fields
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/blur/

This is how you can show things based on a form element input without refreshing the page.

Comment: This is how to achieve the functionality he's looking for. Posting values or storing them in a session as you have suggested has nothing to do with what he's trying to achieve.

Comment: i meant user dint had jquery in mind he is looking to do this with php . offcourse it needs jquery only :)

Comment: This is close to what im looking for.  So lets say Block 2 has a phone # of 5551213... how would tht look using your code @JohnRobinson

Answer (score 0):

Use [**JQuery Ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) with JQuery textbox [blur event](http://api.jquery.com/blur/).